# getting number value from string

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have the string

```
thisIsSomthing=4891\r\n
thisIsSomthingElse=27398472\r\n
thisIsNumber1=1\r\n
```

how would I find

thisIsNumber1

and then return 1 using regex

Comment: Is this string in a file?

Comment: Why would you use a regex for that?  Also, I think we need a better description of what you want.  The way the question is asked, your needs could easily be interpretted in many different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes you really have that posted content in a string, and not in a file. As you're dealing with properties, you should use `Properties` and not a regex:

```
    String yourString = ...
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new StringReader(yourString));
        String result = prop.getProperty("thisIsNumber1");
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading properties:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

/thisIsNumber1=(\d+).*/

It'll be in capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String line="thisIsNumber1=1\r\n";
 String temp=line.split("\\r?\\n")[0].split("=")[1];
 System.out.println("Value="+temp+"*"); // 1* "*" shows nothing is concatenated after 
 the character in the output
```

Comment: If you want that line in a single string it would be `String line = "thisIsNumber1=1\r\n";`